# How can I calculate the Teslas and resistance of an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I'm trying to build a small electromagnet to use in a generator. Right now, I have a coil of insulated 16 AWG copper wire wrapped around a large iron nail with a diameter of 1.5cm. The length of the magnet is 12.4 cm, and the wire has 133 turns. I'm connecting it to three 9V batteries wired in parallel.

My question is, how can I calculate the magnetic flux density in Teslas? I found the equation B=kμ0NI, but the number I get is too high to make sense. I also need to know how to calculate the resistance of the coil, and then figure out how much current the batteries can provide, possibly using Ohm's Law.

Comment: You'll need to use [reluctances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance), or FEM simulations to have a closer value.

Comment: How does that relate to flux density? And how would I use reluctances in my calculations?

Comment: Maybe you could check out a lesson about electical machines, this kind of calculus is common. If you assume the iron has an infinite permeability, the only reluctances of your circuit are the air-gaps. Your mmf is n*i, you can therefore solve the circuit, find the magnetic flux and then the magnetic flux density. It will be a rough estimate though.